# Get Child views of the current selected items in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

When I get a child view from items 0 to 2 in viewpager, it works fine. When I try to get a child view from 3 onward, it returns null. How can I get all the current selected child view of viewpager?

*Edited:*

```
View view = viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

When viewPager.getCurrentItem() reached 3 onward, the view return null.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to clarify the question?

Comment: how many fragments you load inside viewpager?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel 5

Comment: may this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager

Comment: I think the views you're trying to get are not loaded yet. You can use the `void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` method of `ViewPager` to set how many pages are kept in memory to either side of the current one.

Comment: but if i set larger amount to screenpagelimit, the memory will be gained a lot or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the `Fragments` which you use in your `ViewPager`.

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39274141/1559852 i tried to explain how to modify your `ViewPager's` adapter o make the fragments which you use in your `ViewPager` accessible.

After you implemented the code in link, you'll be able to access your fragments and it's views.

Define a public method to your Fragments like below:

```
public View getMyFragmentView(){
     return this.mView();
}
```

Finally add an `OnPageChangeLsitener` to your `ViewPager` like the following code.

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Here's your instance
            final YourFragment fragment =(YourFragment)yourPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(position); 
            final View theViewYouWantToAccess = yourFragment.getMyView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**Edit**: In your ViewPager adapter you can register the `Fragment` to `SparseArray`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     final YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();

     // Register your fragment to Sparse Array here
     registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);

     return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I initiate all my fragment into the sparseArray first?

Comment: you do not need this. just add it to your sparse array when you return a new fragment in your adapter's getItem method. i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out =)

Comment: this'll work. if you have problem please let me know to help you. if it works, i'll be glad if you accept my answer. thanks.