# Calling Fragment method from Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to invoke a (tabbed)fragment method to bring the data to activity.

1. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity)

   - But I get null object reference
2. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747346/how-to-call-fragment-method-from-main-activity)

   - But my activity is already implementing the fragment class so it's not a legal expression

So when the tab is changed I want the form of the first tab to send to details to Activity by `getDetails()` method

```
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getText().equals("Owner")) {
                //invoking method here
                Log.i(TAG, tab.getText().toString() + " unselected");
            }
```

I tried with FragmentManager but no luck, Please help!

**EDIT-** This is the method I want to invoke

```
public Bundle getData() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("area", area);
    bundle.putString("villageTown", villageTown.getSelectedItem().toString());
    bundle.putString("ownerName", ownerName);
    bundle.putString("fatherHusbandName", fatherHusbandName);
    bundle.putString("category", category.getSelectedItem().toString());
    bundle.putString("address", address);
    bundle.putString("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
    bundle.putString("telephoneNumber", telephoneNumber);


    return bundle;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried listeners? Like create an Interface, implement it in your Fragment class and invoke its method from Activity?

Comment: The dirty way: `((YourActivity) getActivity()).someMethodInActivity()`

Comment: @AnandSingh that's what is given in the second link, my activity is already implementing a method of the fragment so i cant implement back to the activity in the fragment.

Comment: @AshvinSharma there is one more way, by using `EventBus`, you can post event form your Fragment method, Subscribe that Event in your activity.

Comment: @azizbekian not working :(

Comment: @azizbekian Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    if (tab.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("owner")) {
        OwnerForm frag = (OwnerForm) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .getFragments()
            .get(0);
        bundle = frag.getData();
    }

    Log.i(TAG, tab.getText().toString() + " says hi"); //test statement  
}
```

Using `getFragments().get()` did the trick for me, I didn't know FragmentManager keeps a list of all the active Fragments so you don't have to use `getFragmentById()` which causes the null object error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a `ViewPager` binded to a `Tab`. First you need to keep instances of your fragment which you use in your `ViewPager`.

I explained how you can get get the fragment instances which you use in `ViewPager` in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39274141/1559852

You need a different `onPageChangeListener` implementation for your issue. You need to keep `lastSelectedPosition` of `ViewPager` and after page selected send your data to activity and than update the `lastSelectedPosition`. Here's an example implementation

```
    int lastSelectedPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Here's your instance
            YourFragment fragment =(YourFragment)yourPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(lastSelectedPosition);
            // Here're your details. You can update.
            YourDetails details = yourFragment.getDetils();
            lastSelectedPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

I hope this'll help you. Good luck.

Comment: thank you :) but what's "getRegisteredFragment" because i didn't find it

Comment: you have to create your custom adapter as i explained in link

Comment: I figured a way out of the problem already :) thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest keeping the fragments logic in fragment. Fragment invoking a class from activity can be done with many ways, like interfaces. But, Activity calling a method of fragments will cause problems.When you especially try to reach a fragment's method which is not shown on screen.

Still, you can write your data to shared preferences from fragment when form is filled, and when onTabUnselected called you can read data from shared preferences in your activity. I accept that it is not a nice solution. I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Yeah I totally understand that, but the method is kind of a getter(see the edit)

Comment: plus I want to invoke the data when the tab (fragment) changes so I it can't be invokes in the fragment as far as I understand